# mongoose useDB with reconnection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multiple-databases

I'm registering my models to 2 different db with mongoose, the default one, and another with `useDb(dbName)`.

It works fine, but I'm having trouble with running tests.
In my tests the application starts and stops many times, each time it creates a new connection to the db, and disconnects.

At the first time everything works well, but on the 2nd time, it connects to mongoose, I can see both dbs under the default connection (`relatedDbs`) and connection to both has `readySate: 1` which means `connected`.
But when I send a query to the `relatedDb` the promise doesn't return (no exception thrown). The default db works fine. I guess it is something to do with how mongoose manages its connection.

How can I fix that?